# Angular - Avoid nested subscribe call...which better solution?

Tags: angular

I have a dashboard component which extends ngOninit function. I need to verify some things before the component loading.

```
this.startupSubscription = this.accountService.getInfo().pipe(
  switchMap(account => {
    this.account = account;
    return this.sidebarService.getCompanies(this.account.id.toString());
  }))
  .subscribe(res => {
    if (this.account.isAdmin && Object.keys(res).length === 0) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/startup');

    }
    else {
      this.selectedCompany.subscribe(
        res => {
          this.idCompany = res.id;
          this.getDashboardCard(this.account!.id.toString(), this.idCompany.toString());
        }
      );
    }
  }
);
```

What I need here is first of all call account service, The account ID is necessary to call the getCompanies service, after that I need to check if the account isAdmin (boolean value) and if he has some companies in the object I received from getCompanies service.

If I'm admin and I'm without company I have to redirect to startup

else I call ngrx selector, i take idCompany and I use it for loading elements in the dashboard.

I think that's not really well-formed what I wrote but it works...I need also to answer if this kind of logic must be in the ngOnInit.

Comment: If you are looking for someone to review your code please use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Simply missing [iif operator](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/iif)

Instead of the first `.subscribe`, continue the pipe and add:

```
iif(
  () => this.account.isAdmin && Object.keys(res).length === 0,
  from(this.router.navigateByUrl('/startup')),
  this.selectedCompany.pipe(
     switchMap((res) => {
        this.idCompany = res.id;
        return this.getDashboardCard(this.account!.id.toString(), this.idCompany.toString())
     }
  ),
)
```

And `.subscribe()` just once in the end of the pipe.